# Oracle data pump impdp to remote server

Tags: database, oracle, datapump, impdp

We have a dump file that we want to import to an Amazon rds server.

This is what I did:

Create a public db link and verify it works:

```
create public database link rdsdblink
connect to dbuser identified by dbpsw
using '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST='xxx')(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=dbsid)))';

SQL> select * from dual @ rdsdblink;

D
-
X
```

Create a directory for the dump file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DATA_PUMP_DIR AS 'G:\DB';
```

Import the dump file:

```
impdp dbuser/dbpsw@rdsdblink tablespaces=EMP directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=EMP_dump.DMP logfile=EMP_dump.log network_link=rdsdblink
```

I have also added rdsdblink connection string to tnsnames.ora file and restarted oracle service ("shutdown immediate", then "startup").

The following error occured:

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

ORA-39001: invalid argument value

ORA-39200: Link name "rdsdblink" is invalid.

ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found

My local oracle version:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Remote oracle version:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 5):

You've connected to the remote database (via `dbuser/dbpsw@rdsdblink`), but your DB link is created in your local database. At the moment you're trying to run the import on the remote DB, with a network link also to the remote DB, and that network link is trying to use a DB link that doesn't exist on that remote DB.

The `tnsnames.ora` entry and the DB link are completely separate things.

You need to connect normally locally - using whichever credentials you used to create the DB link, probably. The `network_link` parameter will then make your local database session, that is started by `impdp`, act against the remote server; so your local directory can be used.

Except... it doesn't work like that. The remote database identified by the `network_link` can be used as the source of the import, without a dump file at all; but it can't be the target for an import from a file.

From the [`impdp`documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL919):

> The `NETWORK_LINK` parameter initiates an import via a database link.
>   This means that the system to which the `impdp` client is connected
>   contacts the source database referenced by the
>   *`source_database_link`*, retrieves data from it, and writes the data directly to the database on the connected instance. There are no dump
>   files involved.

If you really wanted to go down this route, I think you would need a link from remote to local, and to run the import against the remote (as you are now), but to be pulling directly from your schema - not from a previous export. You'd still need access to a `DIRECTORY` object on the remote server, as logs etc. would be written there, even if you weren't copying your dump file over. Even with `nologfile` I believe it will error if you don't specify a directory or don't have permissions on it.

The [article you linked to in your previous question](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php#NetworkExportsImports) said the same thing:

> For imports, the `NETWORK_LINK` parameter also identifies the database
>   link pointing to the source server. The difference here is the objects
>   are imported directly from the source into the local server without
>   being written to a dump file. Although there is no need for a
>   `DUMPFILE` parameter, a directory object is still required for the
>   logs associated with the operation.

Comment: Thank you I'm really new to this, so if I'll run import against the remote, how do I point to a local dump file?

Comment: @Cal - you can't. The file has to be on the server that the DB instance you're connected to is running on. It would have to be on the rds server, and I guess that's not an option? Otherwise you have to export and import as one step, with no intermediate dump file, and getting a DB link to go the other way might be problematic (assuming your listener isn't exposed to the Internet).

Comment: thanks for your help. We'll try to find a way to do it.

Comment: @Cal - have you seen [this import guide](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4173109646282306)? It includes an `impdp` into RDS but from EC - you can do the same from your DB but only if you can reach it, which is unlikely. If you can redo the export you could use `exp` and`imp` instead, which would work in your scenario. It might give you some other ideas too.